# Splice with nodejs, mongoose and array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, mongoose

I am using mongoose (pointing to mongolab) with nodejs and when I do `.findOne` and get a result back, one field is an array of JSON objects but when I `console.log` the array I am getting

```
[ [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object] ]
```

When I copy the exact contents of the array and manually create it and `console.log` it I see all the JSON. This doesn't sound like a problem, but when I try to splice this array returned, I am running into issues.

```
console.log(arr.splice(0, 1));
```

outputs

```
[ [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object] ]
```

So it is returning all of the objects that remain and not the deleted one. When I do the splice on the array I created by copying exactly what is in the array that is causing problems it works fine (the element returned is the one I deleted).

I tried going through the array in a for loop and logged each element and the JSON appeared fine. I have a workaround but shouldn't have to do this much more for it to work like it should...

```
    // outputs [ [object Object], [object Object]... ]
    console.log(s);

for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (i == start) {
        el = s[i];
        break;
    }
}

s.splice(start, 1);
s.splice(end, 0, el);

for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    // outputs the JSON for each element
    console.log(s[i]);
}
```

I also tried the array.splice example on w3schools to make sure splice worked in general and it worked fine.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
console.log("Removed: " + fruits.splice(2,1,"Lemon"));
console.log(fruits);

// OUTPUTS
Removed: Apple
Banana,Orange,Lemon,Mango
```

Answer (score 3):

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

#### Returns

An array containing the removed elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned

`splice` changes the original array. Don't print what it returns, print the array that you gave it after you called it.

```
arr.splice(0, 1);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: It does remove the element, it's just that I need the returned value to stick in a new location. I am trying to move an element from its original position to a new one. So I kind of need the element to stick it back into a new index using .splice(index, 0, element).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the issue after much frustration. It turns out the array of objects coming back was not properly set up in my schema. I needed to define an object that would be in the array, and then for that property in the schema have something like this.

```
var SongSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    url: String,
    source: String,
    duration: String
});

var PlaylistSchema = new Schema({
    userid: {
        type: String,
        index: { unique: true }
    },
    playlist_name: String,
    songs: [SongSchema]
});
```

Worked after that.

Answer (score -1):

thanks user1123534...Your method has worked.
instead of putting playlistSchema as

```
var PlaylistSchema = new Schema({
  userid: {
    type: String,
    index: { unique: true }
  },
  playlist_name: String,
  songs: [
    title: String,
    url: String,
    source: String,
    duration: String
  ]
});
```

create a new schema for embedded properties in array as in

```
var SongSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  url: String,
  source: String,
  duration: String
});
```

and use the above schema in playlistSchema as

```
var PlaylistSchema = new Schema({
  userid: {
    type: String,
    index: { unique: true }
  },
  playlist_name: String,
  songs: [SongSchema]
});
```